# React Native onTouchEnd someties doenst trigger

Tags: react-native

I'm currently working on a React project where I'm using touchStart and touchEnd events to display a dialog. The state is managed with a boolean value (true for open, false for closed). However, I've encountered an issue where, during rapid touch interactions (touching and removing the finger quickly), the touchEnd event doesn't consistently trigger. When this happens my dialog is stack on opened state and user cant do anything.

I would appreciate guidance on improving the code for a more reliable solution. Below is a simplified version of my current implementation:

```js
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

<View
    
    onTouchStart={(e) => {
      setInitialRight(e.nativeEvent.pageX);
      setOpen(true);
    }}
    onTouchMove={(e) => {
      // Do something
    }}
    onTouchEnd={(_) => {
        setOpen(false);
     }}
/>
```

[image]

Comment: If you helped me recreate the issue easily, I would have a look. Mini app, what device your having the issue on, steps to reproduce, etc !

Comment: Unfortunately is hard to reproduce since the slider component is full custom and cant give the code. Thanks for the response

Answer (score 0):

It might help using callbacks in your state

```js
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

<View    
    onTouchStart={(e) => {
      setInitialRight(e.nativeEvent.pageX);
      setOpen(() => true); // Add () => true
    }}
    onTouchMove={(e) => {
      // Do something
    }}
    onTouchEnd={(_) => {
      setOpen(() => false); // Add () => false
     }}
/>
```

Comment: added a photo 
 LOG  {"open": true}
as you can see open is stacked on true. But my finger is not on the slider anymore

Comment: Im using tamagui Dialog for my modal maybe thats the problem?

Comment: Okay so for now i added an X icon on my top right which trigger the setOpen(false). For a temporary solution..